# How to revert changes on a file in sublime-text 2?

Tags: sublime-text-2

Through some horrible circumstances one of my files has been changed without me knowing, possibly by repeatedly having pressed Ctrl+Y or something like that. Is there are any internal buffer in Sublime Text where I can have the changes reversed?

Please save my day.

Comment: for changes within a text editor, ctrl-z is undo and ctrl-y is redo. is that not doing it?  I know with some programs if you undo a bit, then make a change yourself, then you can't always redo.. but if you're working on a file and make some unwanted changes, then you can undo however far with ctrl-z and redo them with ctrl-y.

Comment: it was restarted too. The changes have to be on the disk if it is for me to get any help.

Comment: Well, if you closed sublime without saving (hot exit) you can revert by using `Revert File` under `File` menu.